# Lightswitch Web Deploy - Error 26

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch, msdeploy, iis-8

I have a very simple Lightswitch application (HTMLClient and DesktopClient) developed on my local machine in VS 2013. I can run this locally with no issues.

I also have a remote server with IIS8 (APP02) and separate SQL server (SQL01) running SQL 2012 Standard 64 bit, both on the same domain. I can connect to the SQL server without any issues from the IIS server using a test .udl file. The IIS Server also has a sharepoint installation and all of the associated databases for this are on the SQL server.

When i Publish the Lightswitch App directly to the IIS server, after carefully following Beth Massi's article here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/08/16/10145037.aspx?PageIndex=4#comments, I get the following error:

Error 98  An exception occurred when deploying the database for the application.
An error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server instance 'SQL01\SQL2012DEV'.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v4.5\Publish\v2.2\Microsoft.LightSwitch.Publish.targets
1565 10
IIS8LightswitchApp

The IIS application is created successfully and i can navigate to it using the public URL, but no database is created at all. There is nothing in the Event Log of the SQL server related to this either.

When i publish the app to a package and install the .zip file in IIS manually, the app is deployed to IIS and SQL with no issues.

I've scoured this site, Lightswitch forums, and the web in general looking for a resolution but so far nothing has worked. A few things that i have tried are:

Changed the Log On user in Web Deployment Agent Service to a domain admin account

Changed the Log On user in Web Management Service to a domain admin account
Checked the firewalls on both servers (tried turning them off)

Does anyone have any suggestions I can try please? Also posted on the Lightswitch forums.

Comment: I have also tried the following:
Installed SQLExpress 2014 on the APP02 server - same error deploying the database.

Deployed to my local IIS and SQL instance - deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring the IIS Server to host LightSwitch Apps using Web Platform Installer -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg481779.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I have already been through that article a few times. Still can't get to the bottom of the issue!